# MySQL merge columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

i'm trying to select some data in the following way:

```
field:
+----------+------------+-----------+
|     id   |   room_id  | server_id |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|     1    |      34    |     0     |
|     2    |      34    |     0     |
|     3    |      35    |     1     |
+----------+------------+-----------+


user_position:
+----------+------------+-----------+
| user_id  | server_id  | position  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|     11   |      0     |     2     |
|     17   |      1     |     25    |
|     19   |      0     |     28    |
+----------+------------+-----------+

room:
+----------+------------+-----------+
|     id   | server_id  | background|
+----------+------------+-----------+
|     34   |      0     |  #d91a1a  |
|     35   |      1     |  #f81b2a  |
|     36   |      0     |  #191b4a  |
+----------+------------+-----------+


RESULT:
(I hope I didn't mess it up)
+----------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|     id   | server_id  | background|  room_id   |  user_id   |
+----------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|     1    |      0     |  #d91a1a  |     34     |    null    |
|     2    |      0     |  #d91a1a  |     34     |     11     |   
|     3    |      1     |  #f81b2a  |     35     |    null    |
|    25    |      1     |    null   |    null    |     17     |
|    28    |      0     |    null   |    null    |     19     |
+----------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Unfortunately i couldn't write the right query to achieve this result. The best I could get was that the field.id, user_position.position and field.room_id, user_position.room_id columns were separated. I have no idea how to merge them together.

Can somebody help me?

**UPDATE**

OK, so after some trying I got this:

```
SELECT field.id, field.server_id, field.room_id, null AS user_id, room.background
FROM field
LEFT JOIN room ON room.id = field.room_id
WHERE field.server_id = 0
UNION
SELECT user_position.position, user_position.server_id, null, user_position.user_id, room.background
FROM user_position
LEFT JOIN room ON room.id = (SELECT field.room_id FROM field WHERE field.id = user_position.position)
WHERE user_position.server_id = 0
```

Now it is working I just want to ask if there isn't a better way to achieve the same result. Or do you think this query is good enough?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for selecting user position? Why position 2 not appear?

Comment: field.id and user_position.position are basically values representing the same thing, but they are in different tables. I want to select both of these columns and merge them together just like you can see in 'result' under the 'id' column.

Comment: This looks like a problem of poor design

Comment: Another problem I see is that the server id is duplicated in room so which room and background for example 2 has server id 0 which has 2 entries in room but your result only has 1.

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that there is a 'server' table and the 'server_id' is a foreign key from it, same with 'user_id' which is from 'user' table and 'room_id' from the 'room' table

Comment: so in the 'result' the 'id' column is selected from fields.id + user_position.position, the server_id is either from fields.server_id or user_position.server_id depends on where is the 'id' from. The background is from 'room' based on the 'room.id'. 'room_id' from field or null if it is not in there and 'user_id' from 'user_position' based on 'user_id' and 'server_id'

Answer (score 0):

With the given set of data, you may try below -

```
SELECT COALESCE(F.id, UP2.position) id
      ,COALESCE(F.server_id, UP2.server_id) server_id
      ,UP2.background
      ,F.room_id
      ,UP2.user_id
FROM field F
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT UP.server_id, R.background, UP.position, UP.user_id
                 FROM (SELECT server_id, position, user_id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY server_id ORDER BY user_id) rn
                       FROM user_position) UP
                 JOIN (SELECT server_id, background, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY server_id ORDER BY id) rn
                       FROM room) R ON UP.rn = R.rn
                                    AND UP.server_id = R.server_id) UP2 ON F.id = UP2.position
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(F.id, UP3.position) id
      ,COALESCE(F.server_id, UP3.server_id) server_id
      ,UP3.background
      ,F.room_id
      ,UP3.user_id
FROM field F
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT UP.server_id, R.background, UP.position, UP.user_id
                 FROM (SELECT server_id, position, user_id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY server_id ORDER BY user_id) rn
                       FROM user_position) UP
                 JOIN (SELECT server_id, background, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY server_id ORDER BY id) rn
                       FROM room) R ON UP.rn = R.rn
                                    AND UP.server_id = R.server_id) UP3 ON F.id = UP3.position
ORDER BY id
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=088d3e681454dae453e49959d75aaa1b) is the demo.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I tried it and result is not what I wanted. Anyways, I updated the post with a query which is now working as intended, can you please take a look at it and tell me if it is OK to do it that way? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @KrKOo, I have tried your query with the sample data and it is not giving the correct result.